# Using junit under Android with Eclipse

Tags: unit-testing, android-2.2-froyo, junit3

I'm trying to use junit to test some classes I'm writing in a project. The problem is that I can't see any failure event if the test testNull is a assertEquals(new Integer(1), null). This is the output:

```
01-01 07:35:21.754: INFO/TestRunner(16093): started: testNull(package.ui.test.MyTest)
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=InstrumentationTestRunner
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/TestRunner(16093): finished: testNull(package.ui.test.MyTest)
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/TestRunner(16093): passed: testNull(package.ui.test.MyTest)
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=package.ui.test.MyTest
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): package.ui.test.MyTest:
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=2
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testNull
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=InstrumentationTestRunner
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=package.ui.test.MyTest
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=2
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testNull
01-01 07:35:21.774: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
01-01 07:35:21.787: INFO/TestRunner(16093): started: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(package.ui.test.MyTest)
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/TestRunner(16093): finished: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(package.ui.test.MyTest)
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/TestRunner(16093): passed: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(package.ui.test.MyTest)
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=InstrumentationTestRunner
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=2
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=package.ui.test.MyTest
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=2
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=InstrumentationTestRunner
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=2
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=package.ui.test.MyTest
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=2
01-01 07:35:21.794: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly
01-01 07:35:21.804: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
01-01 07:35:21.804: INFO/Process(934): Sending signal. PID: 16093 SIG: 9
01-01 07:35:21.804: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: stream=
01-01 07:35:21.804: INFO/stdout(16085): Test results for InstrumentationTestRunner=..
01-01 07:35:21.804: INFO/stdout(16085): Time: 0.051
01-01 07:35:21.804: INFO/stdout(16085): OK (2 tests)
01-01 07:35:21.804: INFO/stdout(16085): INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: -1
01-01 07:35:21.804: INFO/ActivityManager(934): Force stopping package package.ui uid=10031
01-01 07:35:21.814: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(16085): Shutting down VM
01-01 07:35:21.814: INFO/AndroidRuntime(16085): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
01-01 07:35:21.814: DEBUG/jdwp(16085): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
01-01 07:35:21.814: DEBUG/dalvikvm(16085): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-01 07:35:21.814: DEBUG/dalvikvm(16085): Joining stdio converter...
01-01 07:35:21.814: INFO/stdout(16085): Shutting down
```

Moreover it seems my junit bar shows nothing and in the console I get: Test run failed: No test results. I noticed as well that I can't run in debug mode and that any Log i place in my test code is not shown. Is this normal?
Thanks!

Comment: Is this helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462850/trying-to-run-trivial-android-junit-tests-getting-test-run-failed-no-test-re