# Any simple way to log in Android NDK code?

Tags: android, c, logging, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm looking for a way to easily debug C code in an Android NDK application using Eclipse.  I've read ways to debug the app using gdb or something similar but what I want is a way to push messages to Eclipse somehow.

I'm looking for a solution that's as simple as using a print function in C and seeing it in the DDMS Log or anything similar.  Does anyone have any experience doing this?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can use the Android logging facilities:

```
#include <android/log.h>

#define APPNAME "MyApp"

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "The value of 1 + 1 is %d", 1+1);
```

Make sure you also link against the logging library, in your Android.mk file:

```
  LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

Comment: If using the new Gradle NDK integration in Android Studio (Gradle experimental), you need to add this line ldLibs.addAll(['android','log']) to your android.ndk options .

Answer (score 40):

*No one has posted info about different log levels so far. The answer is an attempt to make the logging "picture" full*.

```
#include <android/log.h>

#define TAG "MY_TAG"

#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,    TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGW(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN,     TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,     TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,    TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Usage:

```
char err[] = "wrong";
LOGE("Something went %s", err);
```

Link *Android* log library as below.

**Android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
find_library( log-lib log )
target_link_libraries( ${log-lib} )
```

Further reading: [Logging](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/logging)

Comment: When using CMake you need to pass in the name of your target library you are linking the logging library to as the first parameter. So `target_link_libraries( your-library-name ${log-lib} )` then it worked for me. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is probably to redirect printf() statements to the system log (based on the "Viewing stdout and stderr" section of [the official ADB reference manual](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html).

Type these 3 commands on a command line:

```
adb shell stop
adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
adb shell start
```

Then you can view the output of your "printf()" statements by looking at the "LogCat" window of Eclipse Debugger, or by typing this on a command line:

```
adb logcat
```

Just be aware that since the data is buffered before transferring from the emulator or device, you should definitely flush the stdout buffer, eg:

```
printf("Hello, I am %d years old!\n", 30);
fflush(stdout);
```

You should then see a log message starting with "I/stdout:"

Comment: Note that this solution breaks JUnit tests. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462850/trying-to-run-trivial-android-junit-tests-getting-test-run-failed-no-test-re

Answer (score 5):

You can also a little util

```
#include <android/log.h>

#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "native-lib", __VA_ARGS__))
```

Usage:

```
std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
int a = 1;
LOGI("int %d, string: %s", a, hello.c_str());
```

Comment: How to see these logs in linux terminal

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution (using a debugger) is explained here:

[How can I effectively debug C code that's wrapped with JNI in Eclipse? (Android Dev)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846080/how-can-i-effectively-debug-c-code-thats-wrapped-with-jni-in-eclipse-android-d/4942519#4942519)

Answer (score 2):

ADT 20 includes an NDK plugin that provides support for building and debugging NDK projects in Eclipse. [This document](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin) describes how to install and use the NDK plugin. Instructions are pretty straightforward and consist of only a few steps.

This is the simplest solution I found and it worked for me.

Note: If you are using ADT bundle you only need to install C development tools with install new software (see the screenshot) and you can go to "Using the NDK plugin" part immediately.

[image: c dev tools install]

**Edit:** It seems there is an issue with CDT in eclipse juno http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33788 causing eclipse's debugger to be unable to find breakpoints.
Workaround I used is to start app in debug mode (not debug as native app but 'regular' debug) and then in command line I went to my project root and typed `ndk-gdb` (this creates `gdb.setup` file in `obj/local/armeabi` folder). After that breakpoints worked as usual.

In comments related to the issue on the link above they suggest some other workarounds but I didn't try them since they seemed to require more effort than this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's struggling with

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

not working, just add it after each

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
```

Not sure why, but it worked for me.

Cheers!