# Instantiate Java class from JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to create an instance of a Java class in my native code. To do it, I am using the following C code:

```
jobject Java_com_mypackage__myClass_myMethod(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint index){
    int fd = pDevs[index].ufds.fd; // fd = open(....); it's a input/eventX file.
    jclass class = (*env)->FindClass(env,"com/mypackage/ClassName");
    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,class,"<init>","(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    return (*env)->NewObject(env,class,mid,(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, pDevs[index].device_path));
}
```

But when I invoke myMethod, I keep getting fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV). Is the code wrong?

Comment: Your system log probably contains important information, e.g. in which function the signal was issued. Also, you should check the return values fron JNI calls you make: isn't `class` **NULL**? Isn't `mid` **NULL**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use logging/debbuger to find place where segmentation fault happenned. The easiest way is to use android logging system as described
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629308/any-simple-or-easy-way-to-debug-android-ndk-code)

```
jclass class = (*env)->FindClass(env,"com/mypackage/ClassName");
if(class == null)
{
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "TAG", "class is null");
}
```

For example if ClassName is an inner class of some activity you should use com/mypackage/ActivityName#ClassName instead of com/mypackage/ClassName. But I can only guess before you provide your logs.

Comment: I wasn't aware of how to print logs in native code, this was really helpful.