# How to log the jni data in the adb console?

Tags: android, logging, java-native-interface

I want to log the JNI data like JNI byte,byte Array on the Android console .I am trying LOGI and LOGE but it is not taking %formatting string.

```
LOGI("data = %d",data);
LOGE("data = %d",data);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629308/any-simple-or-easy-way-to-debug-android-ndk-code?

Comment: @EugenMartynov ,thanks ,I can accept it as an answer if you put there.

Comment: Thanks! I would just delete question since it is duplicate