# How to print on android emulator console by using C coding in JNA framework

Tags: android, c, jna

I am new to the android studio, could you please help me, I tried multiple time to print Logcats on Android emulator but unable to see Logcats print.Is there any possibility to print on Android emulator console by using Native code prints and also How to print Logcats on android studio logcat window using normal C printf.

I tried this one,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(int prio, const char *tag, const char *fmt, ...)

int main()
{
    int a=23;
    LOGD(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"Print something %d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try using `__android_log_write` instead of `__android_log_print` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Can you see logs which are output by java code in locat?

Comment: Hi THEPATEL i tried that not working

Comment: Hi Aolphn,
In logcat i saw only JNA code Logs only not C code lagcats.

Comment: [Any simple or easy way to log in Android NDK code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4629308/3290339)