# Display Logs of Go file in android Studio logcat

Tags: android, go, android-ndk, cross-compiling, logcat

I have some Functions which is written in Go language and I am Exporting those functions to C(Cross Compiling) with the below command which generates .h and .a file
go build -buildmode=c-archive -o foo.a
and generating the Shared library with the command
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o C:\Users\Nems\TestingLogs1\armeabi-v7a\libfoo.so
which generates .so file.
I am integrating those file in Android studio and the Application is running fine, The problem for me is **I want to see the Logging statements(used fmt and log both) of Go file in android studio Logcat**.

I tried many ways to display logs of Go in android studio but none of those work for me.

Comment: Share some code snippets how you are using log in .go files?

Comment: //export StartTunnel
func StartTunnel(endpoint string, remotes []string, userId string, tenantId string, proxy string) error {
log.Printf("********  Starting Reverse Client Tunnel - v%s, %v ********", shshare.BuildVersion, os.Args)
log.Printf("CPC Gateway EP: %s , Remote data: %s", hasConfig.Server, remotes)
fmt.Printf("********  Starting Reverse Client Tunnel - endpoint %s, remotes: %s, userId: %s, tenantId: %s, proxy: %s ********", endpoint, remotes, userId, tenantId, proxy)
}
this are some common log statements which has been used in Go file.

Answer (score 0):

In the end Android requires you to use liblog library.
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:system/logging/liblog/Android.bp

You would have to check how to use it for Go.

A similar answer for NDK would be something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4629747/9458132

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4629747/9458132 this is useful for printing logs from inside JNI file, but I want to print logs which is inside the library.