# Linking a Rust library to android flutter project - can't find liblog.a

Tags: android, flutter, rust, android-ndk

I am trying to use the NDK to link in a Rust-written shared library with the `aarch64-linux-android` architecture. When compiled for this target, cargo comes up with a long dump, followed by:

`= note: lld: error: unable to find library -llog`

I search all over the internet and on my computer but can't find liblog.a

I even tried to make my own dummy liblog.a that did nothing, but the android app crashes at runtime with a null-pointer exception.

How can I shut the compiler up, or link in the android log library?

Comment: I assume you found: [Any simple way to log in Android NDK code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4629308/295004) and none of the answers work for your case. Which build tool did you use `ndk-build` or `CMake` or something else?

Comment: Show us your CMakeLists.txt and cargo.toml at least.